# Cannot use a NPM package created with Stencil.js

Tags: reactjs, web-component, vite, stenciljs

I'm trying to add [blip-ds](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blip-ds) to my Vite project.

The package is a web components library made using Stencil.js.

I can load the components, but when I try to use them, I get the following errors:

[console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyXQ1.png)

I can use the package normally with Create React App (Webpack). How do I get it to work with Vite?

CodeSandbox Repro: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/headless-dawn-ox8s58?selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A1%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A1%7D%5D&file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx

I've tried changing the Vite configuration and disabling dependency optimization, no luck so far.

Answer (score 3):

It seems stencil requires the library to be compiled with `enableImportInjection: true` to make it work with Vite.

A workaround is to set `optimizeDeps.exclude: ['blip-ds/loader']`.

```
//vite.config.ts
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    optimizeDeps: {
        exclude: ['blip-ds/loader']
    },
    server: { port: 3000 }
});
```

Credit: [sapphi-red](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/12434#issuecomment-1471305880)

Comment: That work for me with react NX with vite and a stenciljs lib. Thanks!